# How can I omit checking array length before using methods on a given array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way I can skip checking array length every time I want to use a filter, map, or any other method used on arrays?

```
const newArray = array.length ? array.filter(n=>n.id=id) : [];

const otherArray = array.length ? array.map(n=>n.id=id) : [];
```

Comment: You don't need to check the array length when using filter or map, you will get `[]` as a result if the length is 0..

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to check them.

```js
const testArr = [];

const anotherArr = testArr.map((item) => { 
  // do something with item;
  return transformedItem;
});

// anotherArr is [];

const anotherArr2 = testArr.filter((item) => { 
  // do something with item;
  return boolean;
});

// anotherArr2 is still [];
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback is invoked for each element of the array. If there is no element, it won't be invoked.

Just don't check it :

```js
const array = [];
const id = 42;

const newArray = array.filter(n => n.id === id);
const otherArray = array.map(n => n.id = id);

console.log(newArray);
console.log(otherArray);

[].forEach(elem => console.log("Hello world ")); // no output
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything, just call a function `.map()` or `.filter()` etc..It returns empty array( `[]`) if nothing return.

```js
const array = [];
const mapped = array.map(() => {})
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: it's usually a good idea to check the other answers before posting - this same answer was already given twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to check the length, if array length is 0 then after the map or filter operation would give you empty array.

Here the assumption is, the array variable is an empty array but not undefined.

Comment: I am slow in typing and often times answers which doesn’t require code but just text I post it using mobile application. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to:

```
const newArray = array.length && array.filter(n=> n.id === id);
```

Or you can create a wrapper method and have a logic in that returns array on which you can further modify as per your logic.

```
function isArrayValid(array, callback) {
  if (Array.isArray(array)) {
      return callback(array);
  }
  return [];
}


const newArray = isArrayValid(array, (_validArray) => {
 return _validArray.filter(n => n.id === id);
});

const otherArray = isArrayValid(array, (_validArray) => {
 return _validArray.map(n => n.id * 2);
});
```

Hope it helps.
Happy coding !